# Facebook Connect Changed My User ID and Deleted Some Badges

Tags: support, badges, merge-accounts, facebook

So this actually happened a long time ago I just never complained about it until now:

I was a beta user of SO and originally my account was located at: https://stackoverflow.com/users/871/andrew-g-johnson -- I used Google to login as soon as it was available

Then when you guys rolled out Facebook Connect and I clicked that.  Suddenly my account id was changed: https://stackoverflow.com/users/428190/andrew-g-johnson.

I liked my low user id and beta badge -- is it possible to get those back?

Comment: Did you add an OpenID to your account, or register a second account? It sounds like the latter; if you reregistered with a totally different OpenID you really can't be surprised that you ended up with a different account

Comment: probably related or dup with - [I accidently unbanned myself because of a security hole in the Stack Exchange platform, but I'm not a hacker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79230/i-accidently-unbanned-myself-because-of-a-security-hole-in-the-stack-exchange-pla)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek - I think it's the same one, my rep & past questions are associated with the newer account

Comment: It looks like someone merged your older account into your newer one (ICBW). I'm flagging this for dev attention. Are you _certain_ that the old ID is correct?

Comment: @Tim Post - Ya it was definitely 871 -- my personal site is still linking there, my meta ID seems to still be 871.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you should get your account back or get merged to old id, since your joined date is only few minutes different than next user id - [872](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872/derek-park)

And looks like that even made someone out of the box, I knew that they had to ban again to following person. His user id changed from 135854 to 157251 on meta.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79230/i-accidently-unbanned-myself-because-of-a-security-hole-in-the-stack-exchange-pla

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without hours of painful dev work manually manipulating the database, sorry -- your account was auto-merged into the higher ID way back in August 2010.

Comment: FYI, this should be fixed for all future cases - the system now always favors merging into the lower user ID.